# How to print the list in 'for' loop using .format() in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, string.format

I'm a newbie to Python. I'm writing a very simple piece of code to print the contents of a list using 'for' loop with `.format()` and I want the output as below, but I'm getting this error:

```
names = ['David', 'Peter', 'Michael', 'John', 'Bob']
for i in names:
    print("{}.{}".format(i, names[i]))
```

---

```
print("{}.{}".format(i,breakfastMenu[i]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Expected output I want:
1. David
2. Peter
3. Michael
4. John
5. Bob

Can someone please help me to get that output?

Comment: Please format your code. Python is unreadable without proper indentation. Edit your comment and use the code formatting button.

Comment: I'm still not certain about how you want the output formatted. Did you want them all on one line?

Comment: hey @gilch ... Since this is my first post in Stack overflow ... I was not aware how to write the content  properly :) ... I wrote the code properly with indent (taken care) in PyCharm IDE. And I wanted the output as below -                   
    1. David
    \n2. Peter
    \n3. Michael
    \n4. John
    \n5. Bob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
names = ['David', 'Peter', 'Michael', 'John', 'Bob']
for i in range (len (names)):
    print("{}.{}".format(i + 1, names[i]))
```

Python list index references cannot be strings. Iterating through the list via a for loop using integers rather than the indexes themselves (which are strings) will solve this issue.
This is an example where the error message is very useful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matias Cicero .. This simple answer from your end helped me to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Python's for...in statement is like like a foreach in other languages. You want `enumerate` to get the indexes.

```
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    print("{}. {}".format(i+1, name))
```

If you want to print them all on one line, use the `end` kwarg.

```
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    print("{}. {}".format(i+1, name), end=" ")
print()  # for the final newline
```

---

```
1. David 2. Peter 3. Michael 4. John 5. Bob
```

Answer (score 1):

`names` is a `list` of `str`, so, when you **iterate** over it, you'll get `str` values.

```
for i in names:
   print(i + 'other_str') # i is a str
```

In order to randomly access elements on a `list`, you need to specify their `index`, which needs to be an `int`.

If you want to get the correspondent indices of the elements, while you are iterating over them, you can use Python's [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html):

```
for index, name, in enumerate(names):
    print('{}.{}'.format(index, names[index]))
```

---

Note that you don't really need to access the name by `names[index]` because you already get the element when iterating. So, the above is similar to the following:

```
for index, name in enumerate(names):
    print('{}.{}'.format(index, name))
```

Which outputs:

```
0.David
1.Peter
2.Michael
3.John
4.Bob
```

Comment: `index + 1` would output the names starting from 1 rather than 0. Small edit but makes for a better output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as per suggested answer from you guys I tried. I got the Expected output

```
>>> names = ['David', 'Peter', 'Michael', 'John', 'Bob']
>>> for i in range(len(names)):
    print('{}.{}'.format(i+1, names[i]))
```

Output I could see:

```
1.David
2.Peter
3.Michael
4.John
5.Bob
```