# Print name of array in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop

I have these datasets and this loop:

```
df1 = np.array([[91,9], [22,78]])
df2 = np.array([[99,1], [21,79]])
df3 = np.array([[96,4], [10,90]])
df4 = np.array([[98,2], [18,82]])

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for i in dfs:
    tpr = i[1,1] / (i[1,0] + i[1,1])
    print('tpr: ', tpr)
```

and the output is:

```
tpr:  0.78
tpr:  0.79
tpr:  0.9
tpr:  0.82
```

How would I get an output like this?

```
df1 -- tpr:  0.78
df2 -- tpr:  0.79
df3 -- tpr:  0.9
df4 -- tpr:  0.82
```

The main issue is that I need the name of the array to be printed. I looked at a few other answers (different problems) and tried these, but can't get it to work.
For example `[i]` and other things in the print statement to try and get the name.

e.g. [How to print the list in 'for' loop using .format() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795644/how-to-print-the-list-in-for-loop-using-format-in-python), but the problem is different and doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: Perhaps this can be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Comment: Why not just use a data structure that explicitly stores names and associates them with the arrays - such as a dict, or a list of tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is probably to use a dictionary to store your arrays.

```
dfs = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3, 'df4': df4}
```

Then you could iterate through the keys to get their names, and then index the dictionary for their values.

```
for i in dfs.keys():
    val = dfs[i]
    tpr = val[1,1] / (val[1,0] + val[1,1])
    print(i, '-- tpr: ', tpr)
```

Alternatively you could install [varname](https://pypi.org/project/python-varname/) and get the names with `varname.nameof()`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the variable name from globals

```
import numpy as np

df1 = np.array([[91,9], [22,78]])
df2 = np.array([[99,1], [21,79]])
df3 = np.array([[96,4], [10,90]])
df4 = np.array([[98,2], [18,82]])

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    tpr = df[1,1] / (df[1,0] + df[1,1])
    # Use generator to find name of current df in global names table
    name = next(x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df)
    print(f'{name} -- tpr: {tpr}')
```

**Output**

```
df1 -- tpr: 0.78
df2 -- tpr: 0.79
df3 -- tpr: 0.9
df4 -- tpr: 0.82
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the name you use for a variable is not something that you should involve in your codes logic - that's just a plain bad idea.

However - to know from which dataframe your output is coming from - you can print the index of that datafram in the loop:

```
import numpy as np

df1 = np.array([[91,9], [22,78]])
df2 = np.array([[99,1], [21,79]])
df3 = np.array([[96,4], [10,90]])
df4 = np.array([[98,2], [18,82]])

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    tpr = df[1,1] / (df[1,0] + df[1,1])
    print(f'df{i+1} -- tpr: {tpr}')
```

Output:

```
df1 -- tpr: 0.78
df2 -- tpr: 0.79
df3 -- tpr: 0.9
df4 -- tpr: 0.82
```

I used `i+1` to get the same output you wanted but using just `i` would be more accurate.

Comment: Why not name things and print them in useful ways? "df1" is a bit mundane but if OP wants to name things and print things similarly, seems reasonable to me.