# A simple way of sending individual messages to characters in a list on python

Tags: python

I was required to create a list that includes at least three people I’d
like to invite to dinner. Then use this list to print a message to each person,
inviting them to dinner.

Code:

```
My_Guests = ['Charlie','George','Bennjamin','Winslow']
message ="You are invited to a dinner on the 5th August"
print(f'Guest invites:\n\tDear Mr {My_Guests[0]}, {message}\n\tDear Mr {My_Guests[1]}, {message}\n\tDear Mr {My_Guests[2]}, {message}\n\tDear Mr {My_Guests[3]}, {message}')
```

Output:

```
Guest invites:
    Dear Mr Charlie,You are invited to a dinner on the 5th August
    Dear Mr George,You are invited to a dinner on the 5th August
    Dear Mr Benjamin,You are invited to a dinner on the 5th August
    Dear Mr Winslow,You are invited to a dinner on the 5th August
```

Is there a simpler code to solving this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print the list in 'for' loop using .format() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795644/how-to-print-the-list-in-for-loop-using-format-in-python)

Comment: Loops. Think in terms of *data* not copy-pasting code. `for guest in guests:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```py
my_guests = ["Charlie", "George", "Bennjamin", "Winslow"]
message = "you are invited to a dinner on the 5th August."

print("Guest invites:")
for guest in my_guests:
    print(f"\tDear Mr {guest}, {message}")
```